# Categorical variable coding in SQL for performance?

Tags: sql, data-modeling

I'm getting mixed information relative to whether it is ideal for performance reasons to include an integer ID for categorical like values.

say for instance we have a table:

| respondent | favorite_color | favorite_color_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | 0 |
| 2 | red | 1 |
| 3 | red | 1 |
| 4 | green | 2 |

Is it necessary to include the favorite_color_type variable? are there performance benefits, or constraints of doing so? Some of the information i've read indicates yes, and other sources say that if your table is properly indexed, then it doesn't matter.

Testing on smaller tables. Didn't give conclusive answer.

Comment: yes, it does as it is part of the relationship, but the colour should be in its own table and your table would be a bridge table

Comment: You basically shouldn't do either of "only string" or "string and int". Instead use an actual enum type; see e.g. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html